# How to make the border stretch to bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, the `html:before` border stretches till the bottom of the page, but the `html` border stretches only as much as the content. More content, more border.

How do I make the `html` border also stretch to the bottom of the page to give a double border effect irrespective of the content?

```css
html{
 border-top-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: double;
 border-right-style: double;
 border-color: #472400;
 border-width: 20px;
}

html:before{
 content: " ";
   position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
 left: 5px;
 right: 5px;
 bottom: 1px;
 border: 10px solid #A35200;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

```html
Lorem <br> ipsum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html tag needs position relative, so it will be the context for the before, and height 100%. Then just play with the left and right of the before to position them in the right place.

```css
html{
position: relative; /** to make it the before absolute context parent **/
height: 100%; /** to state the html height for the before **/
border-top-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: double;
 border-right-style: double;
 border-color: #472400;
 border-width: 20px;
}

html:before{
 content: " ";
   position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
 left: -14px;
 right: -14px;
 bottom: 1px;
 border: 10px solid #A35200;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

```html
Lorem <br> ipsum
```